# How to migrate SUN jvm to IBM jvm

Tags: java, sun

I am having a situation where I am developing my code using SUN JDK 1.5 but when deploy into IBM WebSphere 6.1, I hit this error:

> 00000018 Digester E org.apache.commons.digester.Digester endElement
>   End event threw exception java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18 incompatible with
>   sun.reflect.MagicAccessorImpl

I did a search that IBM and SUN are 2 different thing. May I know is there a work around on this issue? Or do I need to migrate my development to IBM jdk?

THanks @!

Comment: Can you show some more of the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

I think the incompatibility is because of different versions of reflection api on java with which you compiled the code and api present in Websphere.

So try to compile the code using the classes which are valid with websphere.

That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an internal error with the JDK or an incompatible library which is using an internal JVM class.

I would make sure you are using a reasonably up to date version of Java 5.0 and the library you are using works with the IBM JVM.